# multiplying two different numbers by two special numbers to get into max limit

Tags: algorithms, programming

i need some algorithm and all i can think of is manually try all possible multiplications and compare each to result.

**problem:**

-all numbers are decimal

-we have number Y and number X which are known

-we have number Z which is also known

-we have number Ym and Xm that we wanna find

**relationship between them:**

Y * Ym + X * Xm = Z

by multiplying two known by two different numbers and then adding these two results we need to get as close (or exact) to number Z

example:

1 * Ym + 3 * Xm = 14

1 * 2 = 2

3 * 4 = 12

2 + 12 = 14

Ym = 2 and Xm = 4

but these are small and integers

**how can one determine Ym and Xm in most elegant or easy way?**

Comment: Such numbers are not uniquely determined.  For instance, if we want to solve $3a+2b=1$ we might take $(a,b)=(1,-1)$ or we might take $(a,b)=(5,-7)$, among infinitely many other possibilities.  See the [extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) for a good way to find solutions.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Avoid the use of $*$ to denote multiplication. That's a common practice in programming but this is a math forum

Comment: @lulu sorry, i forgot to mention that all numbers need to be greater than 0

Comment: That doesn't change much in the calculations.  Of course it means that many cases will now be unsolvable.  My example, $3a+2b=1$ has no solutions over the natural numbers, for instance.

Comment: @lulu thank you :)